# Pandas selecting with unaligned indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 series.
The first one contains a list of numbers with an index counting 0..8.

```
A = pd.Series([2,3,4,6,5,4,7,6,5], name=['A'], index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

The second one only contains True values, but the index of the series is a subset of the first one.

```
B = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], name=['B'], index=[0,2,4,7,8], dtype=bool)
```

I'd like to use B as boolean vector to get the A-values for the corresponding indexes, like:

```
A[B]

[...]
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

Unfortunately this raises an error.

Do I need to align them first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does

```
A[B.index.values]
```

work for your version of pandas? (I see we have different versions because now the Series name has to be hashable, so your code gave me an error)

Comment: @Ale, i'd slightly modify it: `A[B[B==True].index.values]` or `A.ix[B[B==True].index]`